# How to get id of clicked button in winjs

Tags: javascript, winjs, win-universal-app

I have several buttons in my WinJS page.

```
<button id="btn1">
  Button 1
</button>
<button id="btn2"">
  button 2
</button>...
```

and javascript to add click event to clicked button:

```
(function () {
    WinJS.UI.processAll().done(function () {
        var showButton = document.querySelector("xxx");
        showButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        });
    });
})();
```

How do i determine what button is clicked and set value of "xxx" to id of that button (btn1, btn2 etc...)

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "set value of 'xxx' to id of that button"?

Comment: How to set document.querySelector("xxx"); to document.querySelector("#btn1") or document.querySelector("#btn2"); or whatever button user clicked. 
Something like "sender" in windows desktop programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to identify the button (sender) when you have multiple buttons that are attached to a single event handler.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh710231(v=vs.94).aspx):

> In JavaScript, Windows Runtime event arguments are represented as a
>   single event object. In the following example of an event handler
>   method, the ev parameter is an object that contains both the sender
>   (the target property) and the other event arguments. The event
>   arguments are the ones that are documented for each event.

So you need to define an argument for the event handler and use its target property.
Let's say you have the following HTML:

```
<div id="label1"/>
<div>
    <button id="button1">Button1</button><br />
    <button id="button2">Button2</button><br />
    <button id="button3">Button3</button><br />
</div>
```

and attached a single event handler to all of the buttons:

```
var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
button1.addEventListener("click", buttonClickHandler);

var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");
button2.addEventListener("click", buttonClickHandler);

var button3 = document.getElementById("button3");
button3.addEventListener("click", buttonClickHandler);
```

you can access to sender in this way:

```
function buttonClickHandler(eventInfo) {
    var clickedButton = eventInfo.target;
    var label1 = document.getElementById("label1");
    label1.innerHTML = clickedButton.id.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a WinJS solution to get the buttons :

```
var buttons = WinJS.Utilities.query('button');
```

Then you can bind the event to the buttons click :

```
buttons.forEach(function (btn) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log('button ' + this.id + ' has been clicked.');
    })
});
```

I am new to WinJS, so there is probably a prettier solution to replace the `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. `querySelector` only returns the first match, so you need to use `querySelectorAll` ([see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)).

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        var id = this.id;
        // do stuff with "id"
    });
}
```

You might also consider looking into [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/) as that can make things like this a little bit cleaner.